# C++ CLR Console Application [Cant take adress of Directory::GetCurrentDirectory C3374]

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, clr

I have simple code:

```
msclr::interop::marshal_context ctx;
System::String ^converted = 
    msclr::interop::marshal_as<String^>(Directory::GetCurrentDirectory);
array<String^>^ files = 
    Directory::GetFiles(converted, "*.cpp", System::IO::SearchOption::AllDirectories);
```

I'm just trying to get current directory and then get a files in that folder, and all subfolders. But I'm getting the following error:

> Error C3374   can't take address of
>   'System::IO::Directory::GetCurrentDirectory' unless creating delegate
>   instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to try to marshal the method like that. Try calling it directly:

```
System::String^ converted = Directory::GetCurrentDirectory();
array<String^>^ files = 
    Directory::GetFiles(converted, "*.cpp", System::IO::SearchOption::AllDirectories);
```

- `Directory::GetCurrentDirectory` already returns a `System.String^` so you don't need to marshal or convert it.
- The marshal_as function is used to convert managed types to unmanaged types, not cast values.
- The error you are getting comes from not invoking `Directory::GetCurrentDirectory` with parentheses like this: `Directory::GetCurrentDirectory()`.

Comment: I thank you! :) I marshal it bescause i was getting error. But i am retarded and i forgot the Directory::GetCurrentDirectory(); i have there Directory::GetCurrentDirectory without brackets.